# How to create Exchange appointements for another user in JAVA and how to get all those appointments of other user?

Tags: java, exchange-server

I am using Exchange API's, but not getting the satisfied code. There is my code
I am just adding the attendees but can not add the appointements for those attendees and cant get it using admin id and password....

```
public void getEvents() throws Exception{
        ExchangeService exService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials exCredentials = new WebCredentials("Administrator@company.com", "123");
        try{
            exService.setCredentials(exCredentials);
            exService.setUrl(new URI(
                    "https://companydomain/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(exService);
            appointment.setSubject("Emmergency Meeting");
            appointment.setLocation("City Office");
            appointment.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Recurrence "));

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date startDate = formatter.parse("2016-10-17 17:00:00");
            Date endDate = formatter.parse("2016-10-17 18:00:00");

            appointment.setStart(startDate);//new Date(2010-1900,5-1,20,20,00));
            appointment.setEnd(endDate); //new Date(2010-1900,5-1,20,21,00));

            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date recurrenceEndDate = formatter.parse("2016-01-20");

            appointment.getRequiredAttendees().add("User@company.com");
            appointment.getRequiredAttendees().add("User2@company.com");
            appointment.save();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the appointments to appear in the Attendees Mailboxes you need to send them the invitation and they need to accept the invitation or you need to automate that process https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633648(v=exchg.80).aspx . This can't be done from the Organisers mailbox it needs to be done per attendee.